# Removing dest variable from help text

Tags: python, argparse

While using argparse, the help dialog of my program displays dest variable. How do I remove this?

I tried the `add_help=False` object but that just removed the help dialog for that option entirely.

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("-i", "--interface", dest="interface", help="foo")
parser.add_argument("-m", "--mac", dest="mac", help="bar")
```

I get the following result with INTERFACE and MAC next to my optional arguments:

```
usage: test.py [-h] [-i INTERFACE] [-m MAC]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -i INTERFACE, --interface INTERFACE
                        foo
  -m MAC, --mac MAC     bar
```

How can I remove `DEST` values from my output?

Comment: Please show us the observed and the desired output.

Comment: Play with the `metavar` parameter.

Comment: I ran you code in Python 2 and 3. It doesn't seem to show the dest variable in the help text. Did you mistook the flags (`--interface`, `--mac`) with the dest variables by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @hpaulj suggested, you can set the `metavar` parameter of each argument to an empty string

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("-i", "--interface", dest="interface", help="foo", metavar='')
parser.add_argument("-m", "--mac", dest="mac", help="bar", metavar='')

parser.parse_args()
```

which will output the following result:

```
usage: test.py [-h] [-i] [-m]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
  -i , --interface   foo
  -m , --mac         bar
```

Let me know if that's the output you expected.